# how to filter namespaced getter in Vuex module (vueJs)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My Getter in module called ShopItemCategory

```
    getters: {
        shopItemsCategories: state => state.ShopItemsCategories.data,
    },
```

And this is my computed function inside component

```
  computed: {
    shopItemsCategories() {
      return this.$store.getters['ShopItemCategory/shopItemsCategories'].filter(c => c.shop_id == this.$route.params.id)
    },
    },
```

when I click save the filter working well but after refreshing it gives error

```
Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"
```

and this is the mutation that dispatched in mounted

```
    mutations: {
        SET_SHOP_ITEM_CATEGORIES(state, shopItemsCategories) {
            state.ShopItemsCategories = shopItemsCategories;
        },
        }
```

and this is the dispatch command inside mounted() in the component

```
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('ShopItemCategory/getShopItemsCategories');
  },
```

Comment: What is your initial state value for `ShopItemsCategories`? If it doesn't have a `data` property that is an array, that will trigger this error

Comment: the JSON has data so I mapped inside it to reach the array but the initial state is ShopItemsCategories only without data, I used it inside the getter, and I am rendering the getter in the component, not the initial state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until your `SET_SHOP_ITEM_CATEGORIES` mutation is executed, your getter will use whatever initial data you have in your module's `state`. If that `ShopItemsCategories.data` property is not defined, you will get the reported error message when your computed property executes.

The simple solution is to define some initial state that makes sense for the rest of your app.

For example

```js
state: {
  ShopItemsCategories: {
    data: []
  }
}
```